# grunt browser sync not injecting changes

Tags: css, wordpress, gruntjs, livereload

I'm trying to get grunt-browser-sync to inject any css changes into an open browser when a file is updated/changed. But for some reason, I can seem to get it to work and grunt is not giving me any errors to let me know it's not working.

I'm currently using MAMP since it's a Wordpress based project.

Here's my Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
uglify: {
  build: {
    src: '_/js/libs/*.js', //input
    dest: '_/js/functions.min.js' //output
  }
},
sass: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      loadPath: require('node-bourbon').includePaths,
      loadPath: require('node-neat').includePaths,
      style: 'compressed'
    },
    files: {
      'style.css': 'scss/style.scss'
    }
  }
},

autoprefixer: {
dist: {
  files: {
    'style.css': 'style.css'
  }
 }
},
browserSync: {
        dev: {
            bsFiles: {
                src : 'style.css'
            },
            options: {
                watchTask: true
            }
        }
    },

watch: {
  options: {
    livereload: true
},
js: {
files: ["_/js/libs/*.js"],
tasks: ["ugilify"],
},
sass: {
files: ["scss/*.scss"],
tasks: ["sass", "autoprefixer", "browserSync"],
},
php: {
files: ['*.php']
  },
 }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-autoprefixer');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browser-sync');

// Default task(s).
grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify', 'sass', 'browserSync', 'watch', 'autoprefixer']);

};
```

and here's the output when I save/update a file:

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> File "scss/global.scss" changed.
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
File style.css created.

Running "autoprefixer:dist" (autoprefixer) task
File style.css created.

Running "browserSync:dev" (browserSync) task

Done, without errors.
Completed in 1.478s at Wed May 07 2014 18:47:40 GMT-0500 (CDT) - Waiting...
```

But then I have to physically refresh the browser to see the changes.

I'm not sure if I am missing something within the grunt file or what.

Comment: All looks right... try a Gruntfile that includes only browserSync.  If that works, add watch.  When that works add sass.

Comment: i have the same exact problem and a gruntfile.js which is very similar to yours. as i type grunt watch, i modify say the.html file i get a successfull build but.. no browser is opened or anything :\ any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The only version of *grunt-browser-sync* that works for me with this code is 1.9.1. So, un-install your current version and

```
npm install grunt-browser-sync@1.9.1 --save-dev
```

Comment: This works for me too. Newer versions just don't work the same.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and have opened an issue here

[Github grunt-browser-sync repo with issues 58](https://github.com/shakyShane/grunt-browser-sync/issues/58)

Comment: One thing I did notice is that if I took my current Gruntfile that I pasted above and just ran `grunt` then I noticed that it would work, and output the JS injection script that I needed to add into my project. Once I did that, it was working. If if run `grunt watch` it doesn't work. So, yeah. I guess I'm getting confused on whether or not I need to even have grunt watch with browser sync or what.

This is still all new to me. And I'll probably be moving to gulp after a while, but there is more development for grunt currently, so I'll be sticking with grunt for a bit.

Comment: I was encountering a similar issue where BrowserSync would see that a file had changed, but would not refresh the page. In my case, I had moved the `<HTML>` tag to an include file named header.html, so it was unable to inject the necessary script. After moving my opening `<HTML>` tag to index.html the problem was resolved.

Thought I'd mention for anyone else who may find themselves in a similar scenario.